# How do I pass the output from steps in a parallel task to Catch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I have a parralel state with a few different steps and I have a catch on that parralel state, not the individual steps. I noticed when it hits the Catch, only the input into the parralel task is passed. The output from the steps up until the failure is lost. Is there anyway to pass this to the catch? I have something like this.

```
try {
step1()
  step2()
  step3()
} catch (States.Timeout) {
  ...
} catch (States.ALL) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why can't you do a catch on each separate task?

Comment: Since I have 4 parralel tasks (with more to come) and each have 5-10 steps I wanted to simplify and not have the definition be so large. Also I wanted it on the parralel task so I can use the Context Object to get the state name of the parallel tasks so when one fails I can send the name of the parralel task it failed in to an sns topic.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way. The Parallel Task itself is what is connected to the catch. Therefor, if any part inside it fails, that Task is what fails (all branches within the parallel Task) - as such, Step Functions/State Machines have no way to know whats happening - not really.

What DOES go on to your catch is the error message that caused the failure. While this will ONLY give you information for the particular lambda that failed, it is possible to create a custom exception that contains the information you want to send to the Catch handler. When this exception is thrown (and not caught inside the lambda) it generates the following structure on the end of your input json (at least for Python Lambdas throwing a custom exception - the format may change depending on how other languages stringify their exceptions):

```
{
 ...
 your input json
 ...
"error":
    {
    "errorType": "MyCustomException",
    "Cause": "A stringified version of you error"
    }
}
```

This allows you to pass whatever information you have available to your lambda at the time of the error.

if you need more than that (such as what other parts of the process were finished up to that point) then you would need to make use of a database of some sort - either have in your catch blocks for any unhandled Errors in your lambdas a database sync or some other method of storing the current status/state of your State Machine.